# Executing entire perl program from string in Perl

Tags: perl, encryption, eval

I have a program that is encrypted with Blowfish in a file and a second perl program that prompts for a passphrase that is used to decrypt it into a string, I would like to not have to write the decrypted source to the hard drive ever, although having it in memory isn't really a problem as those running the program already know the source. I thought I might use eval but the program I need to run has a lot of input/output using Curses and stuff so eval wont work as it only returns the last value... Does anyone have any idea how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `@INC` hook to perform the decryption.  Then you can simply `require` or `use` the encrypted program.  For example,

```
# loader.pl
use Crypt::Rot13;
use File::Spec;
sub decrypt_line {
    if ($_ ne '') {
        my ($self, $state) = @_;
        my ($crypt, $key) = @$state;
        $crypt->charge($_);
        ($_) = $crypt->rot13($key);
        return 1;
    }
}
sub load_crypt {
    my ($self, $filename) = @_;
    print "Key?\n";
    chomp(my $key = <STDIN>);
    for my $prefix (@INC) {
        open my $fh, '<', File::Spec->catfile($prefix, "$filename.r13") or next;
        return ($fh, \&decrypt_line, [Crypt::Rot13->new(), $key]);
    }
}
BEGIN {
    unshift @INC, \&load_crypt;
}
require 'hello.pl';
```

```
# hello.pl.r13
cevag "Uryyb, jbeyq!\a";
```

```
$ perl loader.pl
Key?
13
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Heeey so this is aweeeesome! and exactly what I need, this is a completely unrelated problem, I use this to create my cipher object
`my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => $key, -cipher => 'Blowfish');`
But this line seems to break the loop and move to the next object without getting any further. I can't seem to figure out where there is a place for me to find the error etc.... whats going ooon

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason `eval` won't work for what you describe.  While it only returns a single value, that doesn't prevent the eval'd code from interacting with the terminal.  It's not usually used that way, but your use-case is a legitimate reason for using string `eval`.  (Note that you could still end up with the source code written to your swap file.)

Answer (score 0):

Just start a separate perl instance and pass the program to it using standard input, like this:

```
echo 'print 2+2 . "\n";' | perl -
```

With perl code:

```
open(P,"|perl -") || die "Failed: $!\n";                                                                                                                                                        
print P 'print 2+2 . "\n"'
```

Comment: soooo the first thing I did was try this, unfortunately something about it seems to completely freeze up my terminal, like I cannot input anything, no control characters work etc, only way to fix is to open another terminal and kill the interpreter.... sooooo. Also when I try to eval the entire program in a string literally nothing happens in the terminal, the program just runs and ends I am not presented with any output etc